# Changing Java ListView to XML

Tags: android

Alright, so I followed a tutorial on the Android website, and I got a ListView going in my application.  But, the example they had did everything in Java basically.  How could I transform the following code to XML?

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));

ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
```

I know I can't make the click listener XML, I just put that there for example.

Comment: What do you want to transform in XML exactly?

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need to change anything to XML in that particular piece of code. `ListActivity` will use a full-screen `ListView` if there is no call to `setContentView()`. [Here is an example of a `ListActivity` with a custom layout](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Selection/List/), if that is what you are interested in.

Also, please get rid of `getApplicationContext()`. Just use `this` to reference the `Activity`, which itself is a `Context`.